# Delphi загрузка 3D объектов

Tags: delphi, 3d

Делаю приложение с 3D. Есть 3D модель, сделанная в Компасе, возможно ли её перенести в Delphi с помощью встроенных библиотек? или же необходимы другие? Есть ли у кого нибудь примеры? Форматы в которые может сохранить компас: m3d, a3d, igs,sat , parasolid, step.

Comment: Возможно, переносите. [«Как задать хороший вопрос?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @kot-da-vinci так лучше?

Comment: С помощью встроенных - нет, нельзя. Попробуйте найти формат в который экспортит Компас и который поддерживается FMX (FireMonkey)

Comment: @RodGers как видите, да. Появился ответ и комментарии :)

Comment: Вы так же можете использовать сторонние конвертеры, если модель только одна и не требует обновлений. Тот же Deep Exploration лет 5 назад был всеяден и экспортил в кучу форматов.

Answer (score 1):

Встроенных библиотек для работы с 3D моделями в Delphi вроде нету. Попробуйте GLScene она поддерживает огромное количество форматов

Comment: FireMonkey поддерживает "из коробки" следующие форматы 3D моделей - **.dae, .obj и .ase** (документация -
 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Objects3D.TModel3D)

Comment: На сколько я знаю FireMonkey еще сыроват, иногда лагает

Comment: Необходимо как то преобразовать из формата компаса в  .dae, .obj и .ase

Comment: А в какой формат экспортирует компас?

Comment: У гл сцены есть GLFileDXF.pas можно попробывать использовать его для импорта в FireMonkey

Comment: @АндрейДевяткин Добавил в ответе